# Sorting through a 2D array for a specific element in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I'm trying to sort through a 2d list in C#. I have code written that lets me create a list from data pulled from a CSV file, however I'm stuck on the function to sort them.

The list details the shop ID, item, and price, and is formatted thusly:

```
1,shirt,5
1,pants,3
2,hat,3
```

I'm trying to find a way to take a user input, say 'shirt' and return the ID of the shop, and the price. How do I do this?

Here is the full code.

```
namespace Shop
{
public class ShopPick
{


    private class Shop
    {
        public int ShopId { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, decimal> Goods { get; set; }
    }

    private readonly List<Shop> _Shops = new List<Shop>();
    public void ReadShopData(string filePath)
    {
        try
        {
            var records = File.ReadLines(filePath);

            foreach (var record in records)
            {
                var data = record.Split(',');
                var ShopId = int.Parse(data[0].Trim());
                var Shop = _Shops.Find(r => r.ShopId == ShopId);

                if (Shop == null)
                {
                    Shop = new Shop { Goods = new Dictionary<string, decimal>() };
                    _Shops.Add(Shop);
                }

                Shop.ShopId = ShopId;
                Shop.Goods.Add(data.Skip(2).Select(s => s.Trim()).Aggregate((a, b) => a.Trim() + "," + b.Trim()), decimal.Parse(data[1].Trim()));
            }

        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var ShopPicker = new ShopPick();

        
        ShopPicker.ReadShopData(
            Path.GetFullPath(
                Path.Combine(
                AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"../../../../Shop_data.csv")
                )
            );

        // Item is found in Shop 2 at price 6.50
        var bestShop = ShopPicker.PickBestShop("gac");

        Console.WriteLine(bestShop.Item1 + ", " + bestShop.Item2);

        Console.WriteLine("Done!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public Tuple<int, decimal> PickBestShop(string items)
    {

        string input = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] choices = input.Split(',');

        foreach(var Shop in _Shops)
        {
        }

        return new Tuple<int, decimal>(0, 0);
    }

}
```

}

The function PickBestShop is where I am stuck

Comment: Can you show some code about what this array looks like?

Comment: It's formatted exactly like how it's shown.

Comment: No, I mean can you [edit] your post to show _code_ for the array, especially the data type and how values are stored.

Comment: Please read [ask] and _show your code_.

Comment: You say you're having problems _sorting_, but the last sentence in the post is talking about _filtering_.

Comment: I made the edit

Comment: Simply use LinqToCsv.

Comment: I can't add any libraries, just gotta work with what I have.

Comment: Why can't you? Is this an homework? (even an homework shouldn't have such weird constraints)

Comment: Yes, it is. I'm more of a JS guy, and so this C# homework is making me sweat a little.

Comment: OK. In PickBestShop code you are doing a split on items. What does items look like and how it is interpreted? ie: I can understand "shirt" means find the shop where "shirt" is cheapest. What would be done if it is say "shirt,hat"? And also if you have Console.ReadLine there, what is the use of parameter items?

Comment: It would try and find the shop that has both those items, and if it finds more than one, it goes with the cheapest. The Console.Readline is just for debugging

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/241185/discussion-between-cetin-basoz-and-gabecunningham).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Linq` statements.  The following code will give you an `IEnumerable` with the single product Id.  Of course you'll need to check for empty lists and nulls and things like that.  The code is assuming a product has at least the fields `Id` and `Name`.

`products.Where(product => product.Name == name).Select(product => product.Id)`

Comment: That didn't work, exactly. The product doesn't explicitly have those fields declared. The names are visible in the debugger, but not in the List, so calling ```product.Name``` doesn't work.

The error given is ```ShopPick.Shop does not contain a definition for name```

Comment: You can only work with what you have visibility to.  Is there anything else you can dot off of?  The debugger will show a lot of things, including private fields and whatnot.  You'll need to make your code work with the level of visibility provided.

Comment: I can dot off product.Goods

Answer (score 0):

I made some edits based on what I could understand from your question. The content in c:\temp\shop.csv looks like:

```
1,shirt,5
1,pants,3
2,hat,3
3,shirt,6
3,hat,2
4,pants,2
3,trousers,20
5,shirt,5
5,hat,2
```

And this is edited code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //string fileName = Path.GetFullPath(Path.Combine(
    //  AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, @"../../../../Shop_data.csv")
    //  );

    string fileName = @"c:\temp\shops.csv";
    var ShopPicker = new ShopPick(fileName);

    var sample = ShopPicker.PickBestShop("shirt, Hat");
    
    foreach (var shop in sample)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"ShopId:{shop.ShopId}, Product: {shop.Product}, Price: {shop.Price}");
    }
}

public class ShopPick
{
    private List<Shop> _Shops;
    public class Shop
    {
        public int ShopId { get; set; }
        public string Product { get; set; }
        public decimal? Price { get; set; }
    }
    public ShopPick(string filePath)
    {
        var records = File.ReadLines(filePath)
             .Select(line => line.Split(','))
             .Select(line => new Shop
             {
                 ShopId = int.TryParse(line[0], out int sId) ? sId : -1,
                 Product = line[1].Trim(),
                 Price = decimal.TryParse(line[2], out decimal p) ? p : (decimal?)null
             });
        this._Shops = records.ToList();
    }

    //public List<Shop> Shops { get { return this._Shops; } }

    public IEnumerable<Shop> PickBestShop(string items)
    {
        List<Shop> shops = new List<Shop>();
        //string input = Console.ReadLine();
        var choices = items.Split(',').Select(p => p.Trim().ToLower());
        foreach (var item in choices)
        {
            var _shops = this._Shops.Where(s => s.Product.ToLower() == item);
            if (_shops.Any())
            {
                var minPrice = _shops.Min(s => s.Price);
                shops.AddRange(_shops.Where(s => s.Price == minPrice));
            }
        }
        return shops;
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
ShopId:1, Product: shirt, Price: 5
ShopId:5, Product: shirt, Price: 5
ShopId:3, Product: hat, Price: 2
ShopId:5, Product: hat, Price: 2
```

Please inform if that wasn't what you meant and\or you require explanation on any part.

Comment: I can only edit the last function. So this code works, but is not what I need

Comment: @GabeCunningham, sorry but can you elaborate what you mean? What does it mean this code works but not what I want?